# Spring data reactive repository - r2dbc not working

Tags: mysql, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

The query is getting executed but not getting any result.

> router :- api/v1/service/appt/usr/{usr_id}

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

public Mono<ServerResponse> retrieveProjectsByUsr(ServerRequest request) {
        final String userIdStr = request.pathVariable(USER_ID_PARAM);
        final Optional<String> stDateStr = request.queryParam("stDate");
        final Optional<String> endDateStr = request.queryParam("endDate");

        final LocalDateTime stDate = LocalDateTime.parse(stDateStr.get(), DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        final LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.parse(endDateStr.get(), DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        long userId = Long.parseLong(userIdStr);

        return secContext.retrieveUser().flatMap(usr -> {
            Flux<Appt> appts = projectRepository.findApptsBetween(stDate, endDate, userId, usr.getOrgId());
            return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(appts, Project.class);
        });
    }
```

**Repository code,**

```
@Repository
public interface ApptRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Appt, Long> {
    
    @Query("select * from appt where usr_id = :usrId and org_id = :orgId and start_time BETWEEN :stDate and :endDate")
    Flux<Appt> findApptsBetween(LocalDateTime stDate, LocalDateTime endDate, long usrId, int orgId);

}
```

Query from the log,

```
Executing SQL statement [select * from appt where usr_id = :usrId and org_id = :orgId and start_time BETWEEN :stDate and :endDate]
```

Data in project table,

[image]

Postman request,

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/service/appt/usr/2?stDate=2021-01-24 03:20&endDate=2021-03-25 05:23
```

Not sure what is wrong with this. It doesn't return the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works. Answer was modified from the above posts.

```
return secContext.retrieveUser()
                .flatMap(usr -> apptRepository.findApptsBetween(userId, usr.getOrgId(), stDate, endDate).collectList()
                        .flatMap(appts -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(appts)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that reactive code needs to be subscibed to, to start execution. The following statement only describes what should happen:

`Flux<Appt> appts = projectRepository.findApptsBetween(stDate, endDate, userId, usr.getOrgId());`

To initate execution one needs to add `.subscribe()` operator to the reactive call. But here you dont't want that because that will start execution in a different context/thread and you won't be able to return the value to the outer method. This is why one should write reactive code as chain of reactive calls.
(Note: controller methods and router functions have an implicit `.subscribe()` at the end of your code so you don't need to add it)

You could rewite this code to something like this:

```
return secContext.retrieveUser().flatMap(usr -> 
        projectRepository.findApptsBetween(stDate, endDate, userId, usr.getOrgId())
         .collectList()
         .map(appts -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(appts, Project.class));
```

Comment: Getting error this way. Type mismatch: cannot convert from Flux<Object> to Mono<? extends 
 ServerResponse>.

Comment: Added missing operator .collectList()

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'producer' type is unknown to ReactiveAdapterRegistry
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
 Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):

Comment: Also, had to change .collectList().map to .collectList().flatMap and still getting the above error.